# Why Firebase orderBy with asc does not sort "1"<"120"?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get firebase docs in ascending order using this query.

```js
collection("my-book")
.orderBy("chapterNumber", "asc")
```

So, does that mean I cannot compare `1` with `120`?

Does it have to be `001` and `120`?

Because the order I was expecting to be is `1,2,3,20,30,33,120`

The data is not sorted.[image: unsorted]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your data format is “string”, instead of number.

Then first letter of “120” is smaller than “2”.